# Shutting down Ubuntu Server running in headless VirtualBox

Tags: server, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu Server using `VBoxHeadless`. How do I send ACPI shutdown signal through VirtualBox and make Ubuntu Server respect it and comply with the shutdown signal?

Comment: Do you want to shutdown the host from the guest or do you want to shutdown the guest only?

Comment: @Takkat Guest only.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to shutdown the guest Ubuntu you have two options:

#### Shutting down a guest using VBoxManage

A virtual machine can be controlled by command line using the `VBoxManage` command line tool:

```
VBoxManage controlvm [nameofmachine] savestate       # saves the state of the VM like in suspend
VBoxManage controlvm [nameofmachine] poweroff        # simply "unplugs" the VM
VBoxManage controlvm [nameofmachine] acpipowerbutton # sends ACPI poweroff signal
```

For power off by ACPI the virtual OS needs to be capable to do so, and VirtualBox may also need to enable ACPI support for the VM.

- Enable VirtualBox ACPI options:

  ```
  VBoxManage modifyvm [nameofmachine] --acpi on
  ```
- Install ACPI support in the Ubuntu VM:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install acpid
  ```

#### Shutting down guest from SSH

A safer way to shut down the machine in case you have SSH access woud be to issue

```
user@virtualmachine: sudo poweroff
```

This will take care to safely shut down and poweroff your guest OS.

Comment: I want to use the VM as a LAMP server for testing purposes. So after the initial set up, I wanted to avoid interacting with it entirely (like SSH). But it looks like there's no clean way to shutdown with VirtualBox.

Comment: Wait, now that you've mentioned `VBoxManage`, I checked it's [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/vboxmanage.1.html) - there's an option that goes `VBoxManage controlvm <uuid>|<name> acpipowerbutton`. Will Ubuntu Server respect the signal and shutdown?

Comment: I think the package `acpid` is required. Though I'd need to check if it's installed by default in Ubuntu Server.

Comment: I use the acpipowerbutton trick to shutdown some Windows Virtual Machines from cron and it works very well. Unluckily, I have never tried to use it in to shut down a linux server.

Comment: Please add those to the answer.

Comment: I usually just --savestate the machines to make them come back fast.

Comment: @JavierRivera Just so you know, according to [this VB forum thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=39325), installing `acpid` will enable Ubuntu to respond to `acpipowerbutton` signals.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=31574) and tested it - works nicely.

```
/usr/bin/net rpc shutdown -f -t 1 -I XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -U <shutdown_acc>%<password>
```

assumes samba is installed on the host.